# Trying to get data from textfield to ouputstream for a chat program in Java

Tags: java, io, network-programming, chat

i'm working on a simple GUI chat program in Java.  The goal is for the user to choose whether to host a server or to connect as a client.  All of this works.  The problem I'm having is letting either the client or the server chat. ideally, the user or the server can type into the textField and hit enter (or press the send button), and then the message will be sent to every client that is connected.  During execution, the server runs an infinite while loop where it waits for more clients.  The problem I'm having is two-fold: 
1) I'm not sure if the way I'm passing the string to the inputstream is right, and 2) I don't know when I can have the server receive and then re-send the data, since it waits at `server.accept()`.

here's the run method:

```
public void run()
{   
    conversationBox.appendText("Session Start.\n");
    inputBox.requestFocus();

    while (!kill)
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            conversationBox.appendText("Server starting on port " + port + "\n");
            conversationBox.appendText("Waiting for clients...\n");
            startServer();
        }
        if (isClient)
        {
            conversationBox.appendText("Starting connection to host " + host + " on port " + port + "\n");
            startClient();
        }
    }       

}
```

here's the startClient method:

```
public void startClient()
{
    try
    {
        Socket c = new Socket(host, port);
        in = new Scanner(c.getInputStream());
        out = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream());
        while (true)
        {
            if (in.hasNext())
            {
                Chat.conversationBox.appendText("You Said: " + message);
                out.println("Client Said: " + message);
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here's the startServer method:

```
public void startServer()
    {
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true)
            {
                s = server.accept();
                conversationBox.appendText("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName() + "\n");    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            conversationBox.appendText("An error occurred.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            isServer = false;
            reEnableAll();
        }

    }
```

And finally, here's the part of actionPerformed where I get the data and (attempt) to write it to the outputstream:

```
    if (o == sendButton || o == inputBox)
    {
        if(inputBox.getText() != "")
        {
            out.println(inputBox.getText());
            inputBox.setText("");
        }
    }
```

I guess my question is: How can I rearrange my methods so that the server can wait for text from the client and then send it back to all the clients?  And, how do I send the text from the client to the server?

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah, I guess that wasn't really a question.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the problems with this code:

1. You keep creating clients and servers. Surely you should only do one of each?
2. You are performing blocking network operations on the event thread instead of in a separate thread.
3. You are looping at EOS via while (true) ... if in.hasNext(). This should be while (in.hasNext()) ...
4. You are accepting a socket and not apparently doing anything with it. It looks like you can only handle one client at a time. You should start a new thread to handle each accepted socket.